# Impala SQL - How to Truncate Timestamp to Day?

Tags: sql, impala

Using Cloudera's Impala SQL, is there a way to truncate a timestamp by day?

i.e. go from:

```
2015-05-01 01:23:45 -> 2015-05-01 00:00:00
2015-05-01 12:34:56 -> 2015-05-01 00:00:00
2015-05-01 23:45:59 -> 2015-05-01 00:00:00
```

The default `TRUNC` options only seem to enable Week or Hour, not Day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my read of the [tests](https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/blob/master/be/src/exprs/expr-test.cc#L3089-L3103), you should be able to pass `DDD`, `DD`, or `J` to `TRUNC` to get this behavior. I agree that the [docs](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/latest/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html) are not clear on this point though--I've filed an [issue](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-2026) to get the documentation cleaned up.

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you! I was confused by the description "Day of the Month" but now it makes sense.